# How to add javascript to SharePoint Subsite webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, javascript, web-part

I am trying to add code to a Sharepoint column list. I am able to do it on the main page and webpart.

However, when I try to add it to the subsite nothing works. I've tried adding the javascript code to a library to the subsite and use its link, to no avail.

This link is what I was using:
http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2015/03/sharepoint-2013-conditional-formatting-in-listviews/

Any help to get this to work on a SharePoint Subsite would great.

Comment: if the same code work in rootsite but not in subsite, I guess it is path issue. Please check all your script's path are pointing correctly. Use full path to validate.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the problem you're having is that you aren't referencing the js file correctly in your JSLink.

If you change ~site to ~sitecollection it should work so:

```
~site/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/cond_formatting.js
```

becomes:

```
~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/cond_formatting.js
```